# Microsoft C++ Build Tools: "'cl' is not recognized" error even when running from Developer Command Prompt

Tags: visual-c++, build-tools

I've just installed [Microsoft C++ Build Tools 2022](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) on a Windows 11 machine.

I then followed the [Walkthrough for compiling a native C++ from the command prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170), which tells me to open a Developer Command Prompt window and run the command `cl`.

I followed those instructions and got the message `cl is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

Alternatively, I've also tried clicking on the "Launch" button on the the Visual Studio Installer app (which installed the Build Tools). It simply opens the same Developer Command Prompt and I get the same results.

I've also tried running Developer Command Prompt as an administrator. No change.

The walkthrough pages says:

> If you get an error such as "'cl' is not recognized as an internal or
> external command, operable program or batch file," error C1034, or
> error LNK1104 when you run the cl command, then either you are not
> using a developer command prompt, or something is wrong with your
> installation of Visual C++. You must fix this issue before you can
> continue.

I am using the Developer Command Prompt, and I have installed and re-installed the Build Tools, which completed without any error messages.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that even down I had clicked on "Download Build Tools" and had gotten the installer downloaded:

[image: Download Build Tools]

I still needed to explicitly select "Desktop development with C++" before running the installer:

[image: Desktop development with C++ option in Visual Studio Installer]

Since I had already run the installation once, I simply ran the installer again, clicked on "Modify", and selected the missing items.